# How to query from a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have a simple Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM myTable
END
```

How can I do a WHERE statement in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to the stored procedure? Something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM myProc WHERE x = 'a'; -- But that doesn't work...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to make a "dynamic" stored procedure.

Something you might want to do is:

1) Insert the contents of your stored procedure into a temporary table

2) Use dynamic sql to apply a where condition to that temporary table.

Something like:

```
declare @as_condition varchar(500); --Your condition

create table #a
(
id bigint
)

insert into #a
execute sproc

declare @ls_sql varchar(max);
set @ls_sql = "select * from #a where " + @as_condition;
execute (@ls_sql);
```

Comment: no need for dynamic SQL

select * from #a where x = 'a' Will work just fine.

Comment: Just make sure you define the temp table with exactly the same columns the stored proc returns in the same datatypes. It will not work unless the structures match.

Comment: I think @Hythloth meant insert the _results_ of your stored procedure, not _contents_ .

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server allows you to use INSERT INTO to grab a stored procedure's output.  For example, to grab all processes with SPID < 10, use:

```
create table #sp_who (
  spid      smallint,
  ecid      smallint,
  status    nchar(30),
  loginame  nchar(128),
  hostname  nchar(128),
  blk       char(5),
  dbname    nchar(128),
  cmd       nchar(16),
  request   int)

insert into #sp_who execute sp_who 

select * from #sp_who where spid < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a WHERE clause to a stored procedure like this.

You should put the clause in the sproc, like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
    @X VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE x=@X
END
GO
```

The syntax for calling a stored procedure is through the use of [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) not SELECT(e.g.):

```
EXECUTE dbo.myProc 'a'
```

Comment: Then you'd have to execute the stored procedure into a temp table as Hythloth suggested and then run the restrictive query on that temp table. Though I really wouldn't use dynamic sql unless you really, really have to

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that.

The command to execute a stored procedure is [`EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

See [some more examples](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data) of the `EXECUTE` usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use a view or a table valued function rather than the suggested approach. Both allow you to pass parameters to the function

Answer (score 0):

If you want the WHERE clause to be something you can "turn off" you can do this, passing in a predetermined value (e.g. -1) if the WHERE limitation is to be bypassed:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]    
@X VARCHAR(10)
AS

BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE x=@X or @X = -1
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a variable in the store procedure which will be necessary to pass to run the stored procedure. Here is an example. Keep this in mind: Before `AS` you can simply declare any variable by using the `@` character, but after the `AS` you must write `Declare` to declare any variable, e.g., `Declare @name nvarchar (50)`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]

@name varchar (50)

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM myTable
    where name= @name
END
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as someone in 2009 above.