# Calling a stored procedure in the SELECT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `ModifiedName`, is it possible to list the name of all the rows in a table and display the "modified name" next to them?

Something along:

```
SELECT name, EXEC ModifiedName name
FROM table
```

but which would work...

Comment: you can't with stored procedure. But you can do that with a function

Comment: You can't write this type of statement, you have to store SP executed result in other table

Comment: You cant with `sp`. You need a `function`.

Comment: If everything "seems" possible with a function, what's the advantage of a stored procedure?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575260/executing-stored-procedure-in-select-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to write a function instead of procedure. You cannot call a procedure inside a select statement ,But a function can.

Inside the function write your logic to modify the name and use it in the select query.

For example write a function like below.(This will  append 'Mr.' with name )

```
CREATE FUNCTION  dbo.ModifiedName ( @name VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(150)
    AS
    BEGIN
     DECLARE @ModifiedName VARCHAR(150)
     SET @ModifiedName= 'Mr.'+@name
     RETURN @ModifiedName
    END
```

And use the below script to get the original name and modified name in the select list.

```
SELECT name, dbo.ModifiedName (name)
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks for the extended example.

Answer (score 0):

If `parameterless sp`, you can with a temp table. Otherwise you should use a `function`.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Name INT)
INSERT INTO #tmp
EXEC ModifiedName

SELECT name, (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM #tmp) name
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
CREATE TABLE SomeName(... appropriate definitions ...);

INSERT INTO SomeName
EXEC YourSP;

SELECT * FROM SomeName;
```

But - to be honest - I think you are trying something you should solve in another way...

- Create a function
- Try to inline your logic

### UPDATE This is for @NEER

Hi NEER, don't know what you mean with your comment, but try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.tmpTest AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 3 COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
END
GO

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(ColName NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #tmpTable
EXEC dbo.tmpTest;

SELECT * FROM #tmpTable;
GO

DECLARE @tmpTbl TABLE(ColName NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @tmpTbl
EXEC dbo.tmpTest;

SELECT * FROM @tmpTbl;
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpTable;
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.tmpTest;
```

But - in general - if you just want to **read** data one should rather use a `VIEW` or an `inline TVF`. Procedures are designed **to do** something...

Comment: You cant with a temp table. Wants to run for each name.

Comment: He wants to use sp for each name I mean that sp runs with a name parameter.

Comment: Check my answer please.

Comment: @NEER, Okay I see what you mean now... Yes, the name must change and this would not work like OP's attempt...